# fastest way to differ two tables one in sql and one in access

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I am writing a table differ utility for checking differences between similar schema tables in access and sql server. all i want to know that what could be the fastest way of achieving it as i have a very large number of tables in both the databases.

i am comparing two tables lets say tableX in both access and sql with same schema and same column definitions and constraints and it has different rows and tuples in tables i want to identify that difference and extract that difference

Thanks 
Steave

Comment: Are you wanting to diff the schemas, row counts, row values? What level of detail do you need?

Comment: This sounds to me like: "I want to build a spaceship, could you teach me about rocket science?" In other words: You are planning on writing a tool and have no clue about the core functionality?

Comment: LLion Ive updated my question buddy; Nice quote UWE but i believe its rather obvious question i am asking the fastest way to do this i know how to do this but i want experts comment on the fastest way in terms of performance and speed

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it sounds like you want very fine grain differencing between two disparate systems, which does not allow for a lot of efficiency.

If the tables are not too huge, your best bet might be to export to CSVs (make sure to order the results!) and run a diff command against them.

Comment: hi llion i have also concluded the same approach and transferring data to csv then comparing the csv file with diff even if the large files are there it will work

Comment: Oh yes, it would work with larger files/tables. You could just end up with network transfer issues and such if they became too huge.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to check are field names and types, ADO may suit: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_conn_openschema.asp. You will not get an exact match between Access field types and SQL Server field types.

Comment: i am more interested in tuple difference rather then the schema difference schema will be identical in both the dbases

Answer (score 1):

Create a linked server to your ms access database and use queries to diff your tables:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'DBName'
                      , @provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
                      , @srvproduct = 'OLE DB Provider for Jet'
                      , @datasrc = 'C:\myaccessdb.mdb'
```

comparing 2 tables is easiest with a query like this

```
SELECT MIN(table_name), column1, column2, ...
FROM (
  SELECT 'sql server table' , column1, column2, ...
  FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'msaccess table' , column1, column2, ...
  FROM B) tmp
GROUP BY column1, column2, ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Another option is to rely on the `tablediff.exe` utility which comes with Sql Server. See [more info on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx)